# How to select dropdown option according to URL

Tags: javascript, html, filter

Here filter buttons are shown in desktopview and mobile view filter is a dropdown.  We can navigate to the respective filter by URL. Desktopview filter buttons are working properly. when change URL, it shows filtered list and show currect filter button as active. But in mobile view filtered items shown curectly according to URL. selected dropdown option shown as "ALL" always.

here is the template

```
<div class="research-holder">
    <div class="filter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="filter-dropdown filter-btns">
                <h2>Filter by:</h2>
                <div class="selection">
                    <select data-select2 class="select wide" name="select" data-research-dd>
                        <% loop $SortedTags %>
                            <option value="$FilterLink">
                                $Title
                            </option>
                        <% end_loop %>
                    </select>
                    <% include SVG/Includes/ArrowDown %>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-btns__wrapper filterBtnGroup">
                    <% loop $SortedTags %>
                        <a href="$FilterLink"
                           class="filter-btns__btn filterBtn<% if $IsActive %> active<% end_if %> $ColorScheme"
                           data-research-btn>$Title</a>
                    <% end_loop %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="research-holder__wrapper" data-research-wrapper="$Link">
            <% include ProjectGrid %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
$ElementalArea
```

Here is my js file

```
export default () => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-research-btn]');
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('[data-research-dd]');
    const grid = document.querySelector('[data-research-wrapper]');

    if (buttons.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    let currentSelected = document.querySelector('[data-research-btn].active').getAttribute('href');

    const showNoProjectsMessage = () => {
        const noProjectsDiv = document.createElement('div');
        noProjectsDiv.innerHTML = 'The requested page could not be found ';
        noProjectsDiv.classList.add('no-projects-message'); 
    
        grid.innerHTML = ''; 
        grid.appendChild(noProjectsDiv);
    };

    const filterItems = (url) => {
        if (currentSelected === url) {
            return;
        }

        if (url === null) {
            url = grid.getAttribute('data-project-wrapper');
        }

        for (const button of buttons) {
            if (button.getAttribute('href') === url) {
                button.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                button.classList.remove('active');
            }
        }

        currentSelected = url;

        dropdown.value = url;

        history.pushState({}, "", url);

        grid.innerHTML = '<div>Loading</div>';

        fetch(
            url,
            {
                headers: {
                    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                },
            }
        )
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.trim() === '') {
                    showNoProjectsMessage();
                } else {
                    grid.innerHTML = data;
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                showNoProjectsMessage();
            });
    };

    for (const button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            filterItems(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
        });
    }

    dropdown.addEventListener('change', () => {
        filterItems(dropdown.value);
    });

    window.addEventListener('popstate', event => {
        const state = event.state;
        filterItems(state);
    });
};
```

How can I achive this requirement